# hasNextLine() always returning true within While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, filewriter

This question is linked to a previous question I asked regarding the same program, which can be viewed here:

[Writing to a file code causing an endless loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338401/writing-to-a-file-code-causing-an-endless-loop)

I have fixed the problem above and rewritten the function as a while loop rather than do while, but now I have the opposite problem that nothing is being written to the file. I've inserting a print statement to tell me the status of hasNextLine, and it is always returning as true even when a blank line has been entered, which is when I want the writer to terminate.

Here is the updated code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;;

public class Lab_Week8_WriteAStory {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {  

        Scanner whatToWrite = new Scanner (System.in);
        PrintWriter writing = new PrintWriter ("Read and Write Files/output.txt");

        while (whatToWrite.hasNextLine()){
            String writeToFile = whatToWrite.nextLine();
            writing.println(writeToFile);
            System.out.println (whatToWrite.hasNextLine());
        }

        writing.close();
        whatToWrite.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: hasNextLine() doesn't test if the next line is not empty. It tests if there is a next line. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--. There will always be a next line for a scanner reading from System.in, unless it's closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for `Scanner.hasNextLine()`:

> Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner. **This method may block while waiting for input**. The scanner does not advance past any input.

This is what's happening. Since you are using `System.in` as input source, the method is waiting for your input and once you provide it, it returns true and proceed to the next line and the process repeats itself.